# cubic ploynomial with integer coefficients

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image]

the answer to this problem is 72.... i am unable to do it by assuming a 3 deg. Polynomial as strange relations are coming between a and b.... by solving simultaneously.... also i cant get why modulo sign is used for all the p(x).does it denote the value or modulo function

Comment: The modulus signs are absolute value, so the value of the polynomial could be $+12$ or $-12$ at the indicated points.

Answer (score 1):

First, three of the values must be positive and three must be negative. If four were positive, $P(x)-12$ would have four roots, which is impossible for a degree $3$ polynomial.  As a cubic polynomial, it can only have two local maxima/minima, so the sign pattern must be $-++--+$ or $+--++-$  If $P(x)$ is a solution with one pattern, $-P(x)$ will be a solution with the other.  Let us work with the first.  In that case we have $P(1)=P(5)=P(6)=-12, P(2)=P(3)=P(5)=12$  The symmetry around $x=4$ says if we match the values at $1,2,3$ and have $P(4)=0$ we will match he values at $5,6,7$.  We find $P(x)=2x^3-24x^2+82x-72$ satisfies the requirement, as does $-P(x)$  In either case, $|P(0)|=72$ Another way to find it is to note that $(x-1)(x-5)(x-6)$ has the value $12$ at $x=2,3,4$ and that $(x-2)(x-3)(x-7)$ has the value $-12$ at $x=1,5,6$, so their sum will give the desired result.  Thus $P(x)=(x-1)(x-5)(x-6)+(x-2)(x-3)(x-7)$